# Like Function to RegexP

Tags: mysql, regex

Basically I have below query.

```
Select * from testtabel
     where call_id like '%7534567' 
        or call_id like '%7134576' or ..... ;
```

7534567,7134576 are not any pattern. So I need to check any call_id which ends 7534567 or 7134576. since I have many to check without using LIKE can I use regexp to check that?

refered [Using multiple values in mySQL regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901903/using-multiple-values-in-mysql-regexp) and
I tried as below,

```
Select * from testtabel  where call_id REGEXP '^(7534567|7134576)$';
```

But this provides zero records. Can someone show me how should I do that?

Comment: You are looking for any call_id _ending_ with "7534567"?  Seems like you would either want to test the entire string or "anywhere inside" the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` anchor matches (here, requires the match at) the start of the string.

You need to use

```sql
where call_id REGEXP '([^0-9]|^)(7534567|7134576)$'
```

*Details*:

- `([^0-9]|^)` - any non-digit char or start of string
- `(7534567|7134576)` - `7534567` or `7134576` char sequence
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTfpkR/1).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this to match multiple patterns using `REGEXP`?

```
SELECT * FROM testtabel WHERE call_id REGEXP '(7534567|7134576)$'  ;
```

Comment: A minor variation:  `REGEXP '(7534567|7134576)$'`

Comment: Agreed, thanks sir, do you want me to edit with your version?

Comment: You had a reasonable answer first, you deserve the credit.